# How do you override the default 404 page in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack and have my own handlers in for any exceptions thrown which works beautifully. However, I cannot seem to find out how to override the default 404 error page returned from ServiceStack. At present the Body looks like this:

```
Handler for Request not found: 


Request.ApplicationPath: /
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath: /Test/123
Request.FilePath: /Test/123
Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.MapPath('~'): C:\Test-Web\src\Web.Service\
Request.Path: /Test/123
Request.PathInfo: 
Request.ResolvedPathInfo: /Test/123
Request.PhysicalPath: C:\Test-Web\src\Web.Service\Test\123
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath: C:\Test-Web\src\Web.Service\
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /Test/123
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri: http://localhost:65079/Test/123
Request.Url.AbsolutePath: /Test/123
Request.Url.Fragment: 
Request.Url.Host: localhost
Request.Url.LocalPath: /Test/123
Request.Url.Port: 65079
Request.Url.Query: 
Request.Url.Scheme: http
Request.Url.Segments: System.String[]
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: False
App.WebHostPhysicalPath: C:\Test-Web\src\Web.Service
App.WebHostRootFileNames: [extensions.cs,global.asax,global.asax.cs,Web.Service.csproj,Web.Service.csproj.user,Web.Service.ncrunchproject,packages.config,servicestack.common.dll,servicestack.common.pdb,servicestack.common.xml,servicestack.interfaces.dll,servicestack.interfaces.pdb,servicestack.interfaces.xml,servicestack.redis.dll,web.config,web.debug.config,web.release.config,bin,dto,exceptions,interfaces,mongo,obj,pipeline,properties,resources,serialization,servicestack,supporting,validators,windsor]
App.DefaultHandler: metadata
App.DebugLastHandlerArgs: GET|/Test/123|C:\Test-Web\src\Web.Service\Test\123
```

With obviously a 404 StatusCode.

Any help or direction as to what I need to override or change would be highly appreciated. If you need any further details from me though, please do feel free to ask and I will reply as soon as I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code of the default 404 handler can be found here:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Support/NotFoundHttpHandler.cs.

Your custom 404 handler needs to implement `IServiceStackHttpHandler` and `IHttpHandler`:

```
public class YourNotFoundHandler : IServiceStackHttpHandler, IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest request, IHttpResponse response, string operationName)
    { ... }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    { ... }
}
```

To override the default 404 handler in the `AppHost.Configure()` method:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    CustomHttpHandlers = { { HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new YourNotFoundHandler() } }
});
```

Comment: I have done this and it works great in IIS express on my local machine but how do I get it to override the IIS 404 in IIS 7 on the server?